# How to configure proxy in Vite?

Tags: http-proxy, vuejs3, vite

I was trying to follow the docs and created `vite.config.js` like this:

```
const config = {
  outDir: '../wwwroot/',
  proxy: {
    // string shorthand
    '/foo': 'http://localhost:4567',
    // with options
    '/api': {
      target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\/api/, '')
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

And tried to test it with following calls:

```
fetch('/foo');
fetch('/api/test/get');
```

I was expecting to have actual requests as `http://localhost:4567/foo` and `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/test/get`
But both of them had my dev server as an origin like this: `http://localhost:3000/foo` and `http://localhost:3000/api/test/get`

Did I misunderstand it? How proxies should work?

I also created an [issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1014) in the Vite repo but it was closed and I did not understand the closing comment.

Comment: The client (browser or whatever) always requests from http://localhost:3000, so all your fetches will go to http://localhost:3000. Then your server (which runs on http://localhost:3000) will delegate the calls of '/foo' and '/api/...' to the provided urls and delegate their answer to your client. From the point of view of the client, the request targets http://localhost:3000 and from that url it also receives the response.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Turns out it's needed to specify `secure` flag to false like this:

```
 proxy: {
      '/api': {
           target: 'https://localhost:44305',
           changeOrigin: true,
           secure: false,      
           ws: true,
       }
  }
```

Related [github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/564)

Answer (score 49):

Based on the [Vite Config](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html) you need to specify it via `server -> proxy` inside `vite.config.js`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://your-remote-domain.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
  // some other configuration
})
```

Comment: thanks for adding the `server` block!

Comment: Where do I specify the logging and how?

Answer (score 49):

For **debugging** I highly recommend to **add event listeners to the proxy**, so you can see how the requests are transformed, if they hit the target server, and what is returned.

```
proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'https://localhost:44305',
          changeOrigin: true,
          secure: false,      
          ws: true,
          configure: (proxy, _options) => {
            proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
              console.log('proxy error', err);
            });
            proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
              console.log('Sending Request to the Target:', req.method, req.url);
            });
            proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
              console.log('Received Response from the Target:', proxyRes.statusCode, req.url);
            });
          },
        }
      }
```

`proxy` will be an instance of 'http-proxy',
Please see for further info https://github.com/http-party/node-http-proxy#options

Comment: debugging configurations also help, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api':'http://localhost:5000',
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

// this is the only method that worked for me, you don't need all the parameters such as target, secure and everything just the above code is enough in your vite.config.js file and make sure you give the local host port number of your server in the /api.

Answer (score 3):

suppose https://localhost:44305 is the backend and port 3000 is the frontend.

I guess the Vite document is kind of confusing.

When I set `'/api' : {target: 'https://localhost:44305'}`, it actually redirects to http://localhost:44305/api for http://localhost:3000/api instead of redirecting to https://localhost:44305/.

so if you use axios.get(), it should be set to 'axios.get('/api/something')' for the backend server, http://localhost:44305/api/something

Hope this trick is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
   port: 8080,
   proxy:{
   '/posts': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com'
   }
  }
```

})

Comment: Restart your server with provided port number. if issues persists then reload the page

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: I reckon this works with the latest version of Vite. I used this while connecting to a NodeJS server. Thanks!