# Vite proxy: how to specify the URL pattern?

Tags: proxy, vite

I have an Ionic React app built with vite.  It's a frontend for a Drupal server, which is hosted at `https://www.example.com`.

When I build the Ionic app in Android Studio and install it on an Android device, everything works fine.

However, when I try to use the dev build with `vite`, I get a CORS error for all calls to the backend server:

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:5173 is not allowed
> by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

All of the React app's calls to the backend go to `https://www.example.com/myapi`.

So, [based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74430384), I tried to set up a proxy server in `vite.config.ts`:

```
server: {
  proxy: {
    '/myapi': {
      target: 'https://example.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
      ws: true,
      configure: (proxy, options) => {
        proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
          console.log('proxy error', err);
        });
        proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
          console.log(
            'Sending Request to the Target:',
            req.method,
            req.url,
          );
        });
        proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
          console.log(
            'Received Response from the Target:',
            proxyRes.statusCode,
            req.url,
          );
        });
      },
```

However, this doesn't work; even when the app calls the backend, I don't see anything in the console (which should be printed to the terminal).

So I tried to use a regex pattern: `'^/myapi/.*':`

This didn't work, either.

I also tried `example.com'`, which also didn't work.

How do I set the pattern to match `https://www.example.com/myapi`?  The [Vite documentation examples](https://v3.vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html) seem to assume the app will be hosted on the domain that needs to be proxied, but with Ionic, the app needs to call a backend on a domain that is different from what is being hosted.